# Reading and understanding the PHP manual description

Tags: php

I am currently going through the PHP manual and I am having a problem reading the description. For example on this `array_slice` method description:

```
array array_slice ( array $array , int $offset [, int $length = NULL [, bool $preserve_keys = false ]] )
```

or maybe a simple one of `substr`:

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

I do not understand the `[,` that comes after `$offset` and `NULL`. Where can I read on this or what does the `[,` mean and how do you read it?

Comment: The description always shows ALL the options that can be using for each command. Sometimes its helpful to scroll to the examples and see how it works. Then apply the syntax from the description as needed.

Comment: there is a manual page for this (no surprise) http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php

Comment: Removed excess, Reworded for clarity, Fixed formatting, Touched up grammar, Better title.

Comment: Thanks, that link helped a lot too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[ ]` usually show optional parameters. So the `[,` is saying you could, but don't have to do `array_slice($array, $offset, $length)` the `$length` parameter is optional.

You could only do `array_slice($array, $offset)`.